# old app params configuration in panel

Tags: facebook

Facebook is changing all the time. Some params that were in the configuration app panel (now developers.facebook.com/apps) are not there now, and they has been eliminated.

Is there any way to change the value of that params?

Comment: which params are you talking about..??

Comment: bookmark url param for example. That and many other params have disapeared.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change that programmatically via the old rest api